# Push Notifications without Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can one use a 3rd party service to send Push Notifications without relying on Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)?

If the Firebase package is not included with the app by default, could creating / using a custom framework have a similar feature set as Firebase? Or is Firebase integrated within the Android Operating System in some way that is external from an app?

Answer (score 1):

So it depends on your requirements. So if you want to just send normal notifications, then I can really recommend the [PushBots](https://pushbots.com/).

But if you want to create extra features like invisible data payload, you probaly have to use FCM.

Comment: But doesn't PushBods require GCM/FCM services integration? If this is the case, then it would be relying on the FCM back-end to deliver the notifications.

Comment: PushBods relies on GCM/FCM behind the scenes. Consider an alternative push-notification gateway Pushy (https://pushy.me/) which does not depend on FCM behind the scenes. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.

Comment: if pushy.me do this job, I want to know how can I do too, some help? I dont want to send my notifications with others company, how to send push notifications without FCM or other company?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out services like Baidu, a very well known messaging service in China.

Comment: Baidu is useful for apps in China as Google services (FCM) may not work there. I could not find Baidu Push documentation in English. Their website does not even work for me http://push.baidu.com/