# Android background worker

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, background-process

I need to create service for React-Native application that is able to receive push notifications from the server even when the app is closed.

I tried using FCM and it's working great, but I need to make it work without using the third party like FCM.. it needs to be self-hosted service.

I didn't find any package or solution to do so in React-Native so I decided to try to make a native module about that and then add it in my React-Native.

Can anyone tell me where to start - how to create a background listener in Java so it can listen for server requests even if the app is closed?

I am a few months into React-Native and totally new to Native Android development so any kind of advice is appreciated.

Comment: To implement your own push notification some software must poll your own server. To attract answers i would rename the question to something much more specific. Note: I found [push-notifications-without-firebase-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570247/push-notifications-without-firebase-cloud-messaging) which unfortunatle does not answer your question unti your software is for china.

Comment: But the server is not the problem, we can configure server. My problem is to have that background listener that can receive something from server. Don't i need a background listener in order to listen when server sends request to my device ?

Comment: "background listener that can receive something from server" requires that the android-client is connected to the server. since keeping the connection open all the time is battery-expensive :-(. The battery-cheaper way: the android-client has to regurlarily connect to the serverver which i call "polling"

Comment: Oh okay sorry i didn't understand you well. But in order to poll i gotta have that service to run in background and contact the server.. and i'm not sure how i can implement that. Do you have some experience of such kind ?

Comment: I dont want to spend more time on this. Please make the title more specific to attract somebody else